# API Access to Google Doc Attachments?

Tags: soql, api, attachment, google-apps

Is there any way to query for Google Doc Attachments? For instance, the following SOQL queries return all Notes and Attachments whose parent is a Salesforce.com record, but I can't find any equivalent for retrieving Google Doc Attachments:

```
[SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId=:opportunity.Id]
[SELECT Id, Title FROM Note WHERE ParentId=:opportunity.Id]
```

Here is a dev boards forum post from 2008 that is still unanswered:
[Apex Google Doc attachment](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Apex-Google-Doc-Attachment/td-p/86643)

Google Doc Attachments appear to be one of those "phantom" objects which support some of the Salesforce.com API features, but are not fully exposed. For instance, from what I can tell, this object has the following standard API features:

1. It has a Key Prefix (098 in one of my orgs, might be the same everywhere)
2. Each record has a detail/edit/delete page

But it does NOT support the following:

1. Doesn't show up as a Schema object (e.g. through getGlobalDescribe())
2. Doesn't support SOQL

Does anyone have a solution for programmatically (but WITHOUT screen-scraping) retrieving Google Docs attached to a record?

**EDIT 1/2/2013**

A ['GoogleDoc' object is exposed via Web Services API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_googledoc.htm), supposedly with full CRUD and query permissions! But it is not showing up in SOQLExplorer or AJAX Toolkit. Any gotchas/prerequisites I'm missing?

Also, I can get at the `SObjectType` token by taking a GoogleDoc's Id and then calling `docId.getSObjectType()`. But doing a `getDescribe()` on that token throws an Internal Salesforce System Error: 129447016-92475 (-1350247506).

From AJAX Toolkit, I called `sforce.connection.describeSObject('GoogleDoc')`, and retrieved the following:

> INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'GoogleDoc' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured this out: you must contact Salesforce.com Support to have API Access to the `GoogleDoc` object enabled for a given org. Once this was done, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

With api v29 you can now use the CombinedAttachment object to retrieve Gdocs along with Notes & Attachments. Still need to call support to enable API access for Google Docs though.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_combinedattachment.htm